# Configuring NLog with ServiceStack to not be NullDebugLogger

Tags: servicestack, nlog

I'm new to NLog and have chosen to add it to my ServiceStack (4.0.44) web services however it's not working as I expect as I always end up with a NullDebugLogger.

I have

Global.Asax

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

   LogManager.LogFactory = New NLogFactory()
    Dim appHost As New MyAppHost

    appHost.Init()

End Sub
```

I've also manually added an NLog.config file to log to the debugger

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
  autoReload="true"
  throwExceptions="true"
  internalLogLevel="Trace" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log" >

    <targets>
        <!-- log to the debugger --> 
        <target xsi:type="Debugger" name="debugger" layout="${logger}::${message}"/>
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="debugger" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

and finally in my class I have the following

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public static ILog Log;

        public MyClass()
            {
                Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));
             }

        public void LogSomething()
            {
                Log.Debug("Starting to LogSomething");
             }
      }
```

When I debug, the Log object in my class shows as a ServiceStack.Logging.NullDebugLogger which I believe is the default but I can't figure out how to change it to something I can use. I'm sure I'm missing something simple but can't figure out what it is. My web services are in a different project (in the same solution) which is why my Global.asax is VB and the class is C#. I also have no reference in web.config to NLog.config but I assume that Nlog picks that up anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way logging works is very simple, [LogManager.LogFactory](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Logging/LogManager.cs#L17) just sets a static property where all subsequent calls to `LogManager.GetLogger(Type)` will use that concrete factory to return the preferred logger implementation. So it just needs to be sent once on Application Start before any calls to `LogManager.GetLogger()` is made.

LogManager.LogFactory defaults to `NullLogFactory` but never gets set by ServiceStack, so the only reasons why it wouldn't retain the `NLogFactory` is if `LogManager.GetLogger()` isn't being retrieved in the same AppDomain where it was set or it's only being set after `LogManager.GetLogger()` is called or some of your code is reverting it back to `LogManager.LogFactory = new NullLogFactory()`.

My hunch since you've shown both C# and VB.NET code is that it's not being set in the same Web Application, i.e. your static property set in VB.NET is not visible in the AppDomain where your C# code is running.

Comment: Thanks  Mythz I'll take a look at that